# Node webkit has built in SQL DB

Tags: node.js, sqlite, node-webkit

For some time I was trying to compile sqlite3 for NW.exe, so Ican use it in my project.

Now I have found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345597/where-are-node-webkit-database-files-stored), that basically says that NW already has a SQL database embedded in it.

Does this mean that I do not need to compile it anymore, and I can use it out of the box? What is disadvantage using its native SQL capability? Is sqlite3 faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once used this "tutorial": https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Save-persistent-data-in-app And everything just worked. I think everything is already included in NW.

Web SQL Database is based on sqlite, so I guess, there's not much difference.